# Speeding up ping

Tags: networking, router, ping, broadband

We have pretty slow internet which makes working online quite tedious some times the internet is just generally slow, 600ms ping, 0.90mb download. (we are in Londnon, can you beleive).

But other times the internet download speed is ok 5-8mb but the ping in 600ms is there a way we can speed this up.

Good performance would be 5-10mb 30ms ping at our location, which we sometimes get in the morning.

Resetting the router always seem to solve the ping issue for about 10 minutes but then it slows down again, any idea whats governing the ping and if anything can be done to address it ?

---

UPDATE

To awnser the questions in the questions below, this is on a ADSL line, i pretty sure no one (theres only 4 machines connected) is running bandwidth intensive tasks defiantly not p2p or torrents. The router is secured using wpa2.

Comment: you can smoke out the other people using your distribution so only you are on it

Comment: What kind of connection is this ([A]DSL, cable, 3G, etc.)? What is your network topology/layout (networking devices such as modems, routers and switches, and clients such as computers, phones, etc.)? Are you sharing with anyone, or are all clients under your control?

Comment: Does your router broadcast a wireless signal?  Is it secured properly?  If not you may find you're connection is being highjacked for P2P / Bit torrent traffic which as the very good answer below states, can choke your connection and cause bandwidth and response problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen when your connection is saturated such that either incoming or outgoing packets (*either* can affect latency and TCP throughput - saturated upload will mean slow downloads too) are placed in a queue. In other words, using > ~80-90% of the total available bandwidth is bad, and will affect network performance as a whole.

Bittorrent and other P2P applications tend to have such an effect, because they are typically constantly uploading and residential connections typically have rather limited upstream bandwidth.

Do you have other people sharing a network with you? Are you running anything that would use the connection intensively?

---

Occasionally, a router may actually fail - this does not always mean it will stop working completely (at least not immediately), but it can affect the connection in any number of ways, including response times. Additionally, a cheap NAT router with a large number of connections (as is common with Bittorrent and other P2P) might be suffering from overflow of the NAT table, leading to dropped connections and inability to open new connections. Consider temporarily bypassing the router to see if the problem persists.

---

Both the above cases might be temporarily solved by restarting the router - interrupting active downloads/uploads would remove the saturation temporarily, and the reset may temporarily "fix" failing hardware or clear the NAT tables.

Comment: You mentioned torrents, we run Google Drive quite extensively (which i suppose is a long stream but not very wide) and we also sync between machines using dropbox do you think either of those could be causing the problem ?

Comment: @sam That is certainly possible, yes. Others have reported problems with such syncing software. As a test, you could try disabling them all (temporarily) and seeing if the situation improves. For a more permanent solution, you can look into installing bandwidth throttling software on the individual machines, or using QoS at the router level.